# Excluding some files from an os.walk()

Tags: python

In Python 3, I want to run the script below to rename the files in all subdirectories of the working directory of the script so that their parent folder names are appended to their filenames. But this script processes also the .DS_Store files in the directories, as well as the `.py` script file itself. How can I leave those untouched?

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    if not files:
        continue
    prefix = os.path.basename(root)
    for f in files:
        print(prefix)
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, "{}_{}".format(prefix, f)))
```

Comment: add an if statement in there saying `if f.endswith('.py')` or whatever `continue`

Comment: you can do a list comprehension along the lines of `[f for f in files if not <conditions>]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [list comprehensions](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) to achieve this, which might make it a lil shorter:

```
for f in [i for i in files if not (i.startswith(".") or i.endswith(".py"))]:
    print(prefix)
    os.rename(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, "{}_{}".format(prefix, f)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check if the `f` variable starts with '.' or ends with '.py'.

So something like:

`f.startswith('.')`

And then you can compare the extension with something like this:

```
name, extension = os.path.splitext(f)
if extension in extensions_to_ignore:
    continue
```